# how to suspend a job on a Spark cluster and how to resumne it?

Tags: apache-spark, centos, bigdata

I run a job on a Spark cluster, and it takes most resources of the server, but now I want to suspend the job so that another program can run faster, and resume the job later, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can suspend a job and resume it later